# Image captions/annotations in lightbox

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, lightbox, captions

Is there any JS script that adds a possibility to add a facebook-like captions into an image opened using some kind of lightbox script?

**Example:**
I have a little image thumbnail with a photo of my family. I click on that photo. Lightbox pop up appears with original size of my photo and when I mouseover someone of my family facebook-like caption shows up with his/her name.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/